# Rendering Google Visualization chart in email

Tags: email, grails, google-visualization

Just wondering if anyone has any idea or experience on how I would render a chart made using Google Visualization being sent out as an email using the mail plugin, what I currently have is:

MailCashFlow.gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>CashFlow Forecast</title>
<gvisualization:apiImport/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main2.css')}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery-ui.css')}"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>Warning -  You're cash flow is in the red in the next 30 days!</p>
<%
def companyPerformanceColumns = [['date', 'Year'], ['number', 'Projected Cash']]
def companyPerformanceData = mappings
%>
<gvisualization:areaCoreChart elementId="imageareachart" title="${'Cash Flow Until ' +enddate}" width="${1700}" height="${700}" vAxis="${new Expando(minValue:-2000, baselineColor: 'red')}" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Date', titleColor: 'black')}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
<div id="imageareachart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

SendEmail:

```
mailService.sendMail {
to user.email
subject 'Feoirling - Cash Flow Warning'
body( view:"/report/MailCashFlow",
      model:[mappings: mapping, enddate:endDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy")])
}
```

But this does not display the chart in the email received, any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Peter.

Comment: The Visualization API uses javascript to render charts, and most (if not all) email clients will not execute javascript (for security reasons).  You would have to pre-render the chart in a browser, call the chart's `getImageURI` method, save the chart as a .png file, and include that in the email.  Alternatively, you could provide a link to a webpage that draws the chart.

Comment: That is kind of what I expected to hear sadly.